# Streaming RTSP like ffmpeg with opencv in python

Tags: node.js, opencv, ffmpeg, rtsp, httpserver

I setup an http server with nodejs to receive rtsp streaming with ffmpeg.

server:

```js
var http = require('http');
 
var server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    req.on('data', (data) => {
        // do something
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        console.log('close');
    });
});
 
server.listen(5000);
```

rtsp streaming with ffmpeg:

```sh
ffmpeg -re -rtsp_transport tcp -i <RTSP_URL> -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

The server will receive data in "data" event continuous, and if closing the streaming, the server will go into "end" event.

Can I do the same thing if using opencv to do rtsp streaming?